# Xcode 10.2 - openbakery gradle plugin build error - An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the product type 'Application'

Tags: ios, gradle, xcode10.2

I am getting the below error when I try to build my project. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

I am using -

```
org.openbakery:xcode-plugin:0.15.4.develop.+
gradle 5.3.1
Xcode 10.2

Build settings from command line:
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY =
    CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED = NO
    DSTROOT = /Users/milfar/build/client/build/dst
    OBJROOT = /Users/milfar/build/client/build/obj
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/milfar/build/client/build/shared
    SYMROOT = /Users/milfar/build/client/build/sym

    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    Build system information
    error: An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for         the product type 'Application'. (in target 'RRiOSClient')

** BUILD FAILED **
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error. Adding
`additionalParameters = "CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO"`
to `xcodebuild` step in `build.gradle` worked for me.

Comment: just for future reference, this was fixed with "org.openbakery:xcode-plugin:0.19.1.develop.+".  the "additionalParameters" option is not required anymore